# How to change the selected text color in pydev / eclipse dark theme

Tags: eclipse, pydev

I am using Pydev / Eclipse with dark theme.
how can I change the selection color? Here's an screenshot showing a part that is selected and is highlighted with a color that is too bright and makes the foreground not readable:

[image]

I followed settings of appearance color options in `General > Editors > Text Editors` as well as `General > Editors > Text Editors > Annotations`, but I couldn't find any option for changing that bright blueish color.

Here's an image showing my current setting (as you can see, the background selection color is set as a color that is totally different from this light blue color).
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have to restart your Eclipse first to see that 'selection background color' changed for python files.

Comment: got it.. *finally* 

Answer (score 0):

The best answer to this is found [here](https://www.pydev.org/manual_adv_editor_prefs.html), Which inherits from General > Editors > Text Editors.  There is also General > Editors > Text Editors > Annotations, which is where I found "Breakpoints (PyDev) which had the color I was finding offensive to my eyes.

Happy Hunting!

[image]

Short answer:

- Preferences > PyDev > Editor.